# How to get list of custom CSS properties

Tags: css, variables

I'm looking into custom CSS properties and have come up with the code below.

If I put the CSS inline using a STYLE attribute on the canvas tag (like this: style="--rgLinewidth: 3" ) then I can get the custom CSS values using the script shown below.

But using a  tag, as below, then it doesn't show the custom CSS properties.

Is it possible to? And if so how?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            canvas#cvs {
                --rgLinewidth: 3;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <canvas id="cvs" width="600" height="250">[No canvas support]</canvas>

     <script>
        canvas = document.getElementById("cvs");
        styles = window.getComputedStyle(canvas);

        alert(styles.getPropertyValue('background-color'));
        alert(styles.getPropertyValue('--rgLinewidth'));

        for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
            if (canvas.style[i].indexOf('--rg') === 0) {
                var value = styles.getPropertyValue(canvas.style[i]);
                alert([canvas.style[i], value]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you query for computed style and then attempt to retrieve values of corresponding properties from the *inline* style, where they do not exist -- your canvas does not define an inline style. You need to query the values through the same `styles` object where you find the properties.

Consider the following function which when passed an element, will search through its computed style and return the value of the first CSS variable whose name starts with `--rg`:

```
function find_first_rg_value(el) {
    var styles = getComputedStyle(el);
    for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
        if (styles[i].startsWith('--rg')) {
            return styles.getPropertyValue(styles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

(Use like `find_first_rg_value(canvas)`)

The difference between my approach and yours is, as I said, that you attempt to fetch the value from `canvas.style[i]`, but `canvas.style` is effectively **empty**. Use `styles` instead.

Computed style (`getComputedStyle`), as the name implies, contains "summary" style computed per CSS cascading, inheriting, and so on, with inline style, if any, applied on top (overriding priority). Assigning inline style therefore affects the computed style, but querying inline style *only gives you inline style you assigned, no more.*

This means that in most cases like yours one would want to use `getComputedStyle`. Additionally, since CSS variables cannot be queried using `style.fontName` syntax, you need to use `getPropertyValue` function for these (all dashes *intact* in the passed property name), regardless if you are dealing with an inline or computed style object.

Comment: Oki doki, I now have this:  canvas = document.getElementById("cvs");
        styles = getComputedStyle(canvas);

        for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            if (styles[i].indexOf('--rg') === 0) {
                alert(styles[i]);
                alert(styles.getPropertyValue(styles[i]));
            }
        }                 But it only works in Firefox. Not chrome or IE. This is what I need - to find all of the --rg values whether they're defing in a style block or an inline style attribute.

Comment: Is that because only FF fully supports CSS variables?

Comment: Here's a test page I've setup. It only works in FF: http://www.rgraph.net/tests/css-variables.html

Comment: That's right -- even though your code now seems very good (although you can use `Array.prototype.filter` instead, leaving this an exercize), I have also found out that Chrome (51 in my case) does *not* include custom properties during enumeration using array subscript or `item()` calls. `getPropertyValue` works fine though -- meaning that you can retrieve the values of properties by name, but you cannot do things like searching for certain custom properties that begin with `--rg`. I've sent an inquiry to the editor of https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/

Comment: An after though: Is there any other current way to do custom CSS settings?

Comment: Not that I can think of. It would probably help immensely if the user agent did *not* hide custom CSS properties, as obviously you then would have no way of even finding them. Short of writing your own CSS parser in JavaScript, and even then you'd be pulling your hair out implementing the cascading when it comes to the DOM elements. I'd say that the iteration described in my previous comment, which does not work in Chrome, is the most straightforward way to go.